# there doesn't seem to be a polymer-layout event

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I'm looking for an event fired by `polymer-layout` when it's finished laying out, similar to the `polymer-grid-layout` event. Doesn't seem to be one. Am I missing something?

After my attempts at polymer-grid-layout ([Autosizing canvas inside a polymer grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816467/autosizing-canvas-inside-a-polymer-grid-layout)) I've decided to convert everything to nested polymer-layouts instead. After a few hiccups (*e.g. the dart version of polymer-layout doesn't work if you put polymer-layout as an element directly under template, whereas the js version does - don't know which is wrong*) the approach seems to be working.

The one exception is that I was previously relying on `polymer-grid-layout` to tell me when the canvas had been resized properly. But with `polymer-layout` I have the same timing problem but without the same solution it appears.

Any way around this?

thanks

Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart polymer_element/polymer_ui_element are a bit outdated. I'll take a look at what changes were be made in JS polymer-layout since I last revisited Dart polymer-layout (probably Mo/Di).

Can you please create an issue in https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_elements so you get notified when the update is made.

Comment: I published a new version (0.1.2) that fires an event 'polymer-layout' when layout is done.

Comment: I published an update that contains polymer-layout which fires 'polymer-layout' when layout is done.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. SO doesn't email me so I hadn't realised you'd implemented the fix. It seems to work perfectly. Thanks a million. BTW you named the stream `onPolymerGridLayout` rather than `onPolymerLayout` which I'm guessing is a copy n paste error ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are right that `polymer-layout` is missing a `layout` event. I filed an issue here https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-layout/issues/3

In the meantime, you should be able to capture the timeline in `attached`.

```
attached: function() {
  this.async(function() {
   this.async(this.layoutHappened);
  });
},
layoutHappened: function() {
}
```

I used nested `async` because I don't want to worry about whose `attached` is called first (this one, or the one in the `polymer-layout`). And yes, this is exactly the kind of fiddly construction that is avoided by having an event.

Comment: thanks that works roughly two out of every three times in dart. Adding a third async seems to make it work reliably.

BTW I just added https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/434 to request having a lifecycle event for componentLaidOut