# Autosizing canvas to take full size of it's container

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm updating my dart polymer app to the latest polymer, core-elements and paper-elements. I was previously using using polymer-elements and in that polymer-layout had a on-polymer-layout event that I was using to help size a canvas element to take the entire size of it's container (see [Autosizing canvas inside a polymer grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816467/autosizing-canvas-inside-a-polymer-grid-layout)).

I can't find an equivalent int core-elements so I'm back to square one. How do I handle this now?

I'm back to the point where I was before I used the polymer-layout event. I can get the container to size to the full browser width but it's height is the default height of the canvas. If I resize the browser window it works so it is an initialisation problem.
Prior to the polymer-layout event being added I had to use a hack with a timeout. That was really flakey so I'm praying that there is a clean way in the new core-elements that I'm missing.

See also [there doesn't seem to be a polymer-layout event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111447/there-doesnt-seem-to-be-a-polymer-layout-event)

**My code**

*HTML*

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_slider.html">

<polymer-element name="delme-canvas">

  <template>
    <style>
      #top {
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #slider-container {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
      }
      paper-slider {
        width: 150px;
      }
      canvas {
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
      #canvasContainer {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <section id="top" vertical layout flex>
      <section id="section" horizontal layout>
        <div id="slider-container" center horizontal layout>
          <div id="label">Roundness</div>
          <paper-slider id="paper_slider" editable min="0" max="100" step="0.1"></paper-slider>
        </div>
        <div id="div" flex></div>
      </section>
      <section id="canvasContainer" flex>
        <canvas id="canvas" flex></canvas>
      </section>
    </section>
  </template>

  <script type="application/dart" src="delme_canvas.dart">
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

*Dart*

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('delme-canvas')
class CanvasViewElement extends PolymerElement  {

  CanvasElement canvas;
  HtmlElement canvasContainer;

  CanvasViewElement.created() : super.created();

  void _resize() {
    if (canvasContainer.clientWidth == 0)
      return;
    canvas.width = canvasContainer.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasContainer.clientHeight;


    _redraw();
  }

  void _redraw() {
    final context = canvas.context2D;
    context.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    context.stroke();
  }

  @override
  void ready() {
    canvas = $['canvas'];
    canvasContainer = $['canvasContainer'];

    window.onResize.listen((_) {
      _resize();
    });

    _resize();

  }

}
```

*index.hml*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>delme</title>
    <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="delme_canvas.html">
  </head>
<body unresolved fit vertical layout>
  <delme-canvas flex></delme-canvas>
  <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you don't use a core/paper layout element just CSS. CSS doesn't fire events. Or did I miss something in your code? Can you try to add a `_rezise()` in `attached()` after `super.attached()`?

Comment: Hi Günter. I did port my code to use the CSS attributes instead of the polymer-layout element. But I didn't see any event advertised on the core-layout element. Did I miss something? Thanks for your suggestions. I'll try them out on the weekend

Comment: BTW I just looked at https://github.com/Polymer/core-layout and it now says "DEPRECATED (in favor of layout attributes)"

Answer (score 1):

I tried Günter's suggestion of using `attached` but that didn't work either. However, in the process, I discovered there is a new (since my original code was written) lifecycle event called `domReady`. This does seem to do the trick.

So the `ready` method changes to `domReady` like

```
@override
void domReady() {
  canvas = $['canvas'];
  canvasContainer = $['canvasContainer'];

  window.onResize.listen((_) {
    _resize();
  });

  _resize();

}
```